# Matching substring to table column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I have a mapping table which defines access.

```
   Us | Them
    ----------
    1    MA
    2    LA
    3    NA
    4    MA
```

Customers send in their role and we return our role which represents access inside our system.
A simple example is

- MA = Master access
- LA = Limited access
- NA = No access
- SA = Some access

We now will be receiving a list of roles from one of our customers, 
this will be in the form of "MA;LA;NA" or "LA;NA" or even "LA;XX"

What I need to do is return the highest role back to them. 
SO if it exists in our table a users role becomes the highest possible access.   Input is "LA;MA" I return 1.
Input is "NA;LA" I return 2.
Input is "does not exist" I return 3.

Again this is a simple example they have of 60 roles defined.
My question is what is a clean way of doing this?

I have a working solution which has a series of IF's and ELSE IF's where if the inputted string is like "MA" it represents a 1 and move on. However the code is rather verbose and pretty ugly, order matters and if the customer requests a new role say "Orange" and we insert it into the mapping table, I then would have to edit the stored procedure.

Any thoughts to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will suggest to have a table valued function. This function will accept your string as an input parameter and then return a table by splitting the inputs separated by ";" in different rows with an index ID. You can use this function internally with you logic and determine the MAX(Us) from mapping table. Below is the sample example for the function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[funcSplit] ( @string VARCHAR(MAX) )
RETURNS
 @List TABLE ([Name] [nvarchar] (500))
AS
BEGIN

 DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(255)
 DECLARE @pos INT

 WHILE CHARINDEX(';', @string ) > 0
 BEGIN
  SELECT @pos  = CHARINDEX(';', @string )
  SELECT @name = SUBSTRING(@string , 1, @pos-1)

  INSERT INTO @List
  SELECT @name

  SELECT @string = SUBSTRING(@string , @pos+1, LEN(@string )-@pos)
 END

 INSERT INTO @List
 SELECT @string 

 RETURN
END
```

Once implemented, use this function as below in your own logic to determine the roles.

```
SELECT MAX(us)
FROM YourMappingTable AS A
     INNER JOIN funcSplit('MA;LA') AS B
     ON A.Them = B.Name
```

Only thing is remaining is to include an exception for the NA or "Input Does not exists" case which can be easily handled.

Comment: OH GOD NO - a multi-statement table-valued function like this will cause a serial zone in your execution plan for any query that calls it, and you'll get wacko estimates of the number of rows that will come back from this. Do *not* do this.

Comment: Hi Brent, I have implemented the same kind of solution and its working great in the prod env too. If done cautiously with spending fair amount of time in analyzing and testing I guess it will not do any harm. Yes it can be harmful in many scenarios that I agree.

Answer (score 1):

Add a table with the list of role rankings, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Roles 
(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
 RoleAbbrevation VARCHAR(20),
 Ranking INT);
```

Then, when you get the list of roles, join to this table, and sort by ranking descending (or ascending, if you're looking for lowest privilege).

Comment: it would be work only with predefined list of combination, as I understand the problem - is dynamic list of roles from customer (any combinations). My way - I will prefer do this in ETL packet - split roles to component (convert row to column) than, match 1-to-1 and combine, add to the table values - MA==0, LA==1, NA==3, SA ==4, than sum converted results (this logic need to be checked for return always unique hash)

Comment: @a_vlad the list of combinations has to be defined because you have to set the order. You can't order things based on unknown data - if you don't know a role's hierarchy rating, then you can't sort it.

Comment: it possible - internal table have single value column, for example easiest way - second table - client and single value column (as I told before, split by ETL) - than simple JOIN, other variant also possible